# How to determine upsell products in shopping cart

Tags: cart, shopping-cart

In cart items list, is there any data to determine whether products were added from upsell (and realated, cross sell if any)?

Does Magento provide a built-in data for this or I have to do myself by modifying database?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to find out if a product was added to the cart from the related products but that's not reliable.
For upsells and crosssels there is no out of the box way of doing it.
The idea is that when you add a product to the cart, the full request is remembered in a quote item option.
So if you check the checkbox for one ore more related products and add them to the cart along with the main product the `info_buyRequest` option of the quote item for the main product looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [uenc] => aHR0cDovLzEyNy4wLjAuMS9tYWdlbnRvL2luZGV4LnBocC9jYXRhbG9nL3Byb2R1Y3Qvdmlldy9pZC8xNzcv
    [product] => 177 //main product id
    [related_product] => 161 //related product id. If there are more they will be separated by comma (161,162)
    [qty] => 0
)
```

So what you can do, is to loop through the quote items remember each product id that is located in the `related_product` member.
Something like this.
Let's say that `$quote` is the quote (cart) object.

```
$related = array();
foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
    $option = unserialize($item->getOptionByCode('info_buyRequest')->getValue());
    if (isset($option['related_product'])) {
        $relatedProducts = explode(',', $option['related_product']);
        foreach ($relatedProducts as $id) {
            $related[$id] = 1; //remember the id in key so we won't have duplicates
        }
    }
}
$related = array_keys($related);
```

In $related you have all the product ids that were added as related.

But this theory falls apart if you add a main product with a related product to the cart and the remove the main product from the cart.

Comment: Just back home and read your answer, it helps me got some idea. My correct scenario is: when add a product (to my custom controller), programmatically I add another product and mark it as related (or upsell). Eg: add a suit to cart then also add a shirt, and I want to know what shirt is belong to this suit. I think I should add some additional data to seesion's, to quote's,.. data. Is there any other suggestion? Thank you.

Comment: I think you should add a new column in the sales_flat_quote_item table and populate that column with the value you need.

Comment: That's what I thought at the first, just try to know if there's some better solutions. I will follow your suggestion then come back to let you, and people who may need to, know.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify upsell, cross-sell and related products manually when create or edit products.  See corresponding tabs in admin > catalog > products.

There are also some modules at the magento connect, that can show the lists based on together bought or most viewed products.

Comment: You might misunderstood my mean. My meant: (already add some products to cart) in cart items list, how to determine what products were added from (or refered from) upsell listing (instead of adding from its product page)

Comment: Thanks for the carification.  I believe you'd better use google analytics event to track the source. See `_trackEvent(category, action, opt_label, opt_value, opt_noninteraction)`

Comment: I got ya. I will use your suggestion to track in GA. But I need this infor to do something directly inside shopping cart page. Thank you.

Comment: In this case you need to add a proxy script, that adds something to the session or to the quote object, as there are no default flags.

Comment: Then I have to customize it. Thank you. I will.